# Unable to import materialize in a Angular 4 project

Tags: angular, frameworks, materialize

i'm trying to import materialize in my Angular 4 project from this tutorial (https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-materialize) but my class to html tag doesn't appear in my view. I modified my angular-cli.json file and add the module in my app.module.ts without success... Any ideas?

{
- Angular/CLI version: 1.0.4
- Angular/common version: 4.1.3
}

Comment: how do you see that you failed? is it errors in the console ?

Comment: no, the class that i applied doesn't work

Comment: have you run "npm install materialize-css --save"? i mean you need also install the original materializecss ...

Comment: yep i followed all the tutorial  
and i installed materializecss with npm

Comment: i can only suggest you to follow the README of thier repo https://github.com/InfomediaLtd/angular2-materialize